# Python - re.error: unterminated character set at position

Tags: python

The following code:

```
text = "I'm a string that contains this characters {}, [], ()"
slice = "this characters {}, [], ()"
print([ (m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(slice, text) ])
```

Shows the error:

```
re.error: unterminated character set at position 12
```

That is, most likely, because of the metacharacters "{}, [], ()". Is there any regular expression that can make `finditer` ignore it?

Comment: If you're just looking for literal text, there's no reason to use regex. But if you insist, you need to [escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) special characters in the regex.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You must escape the special characters in your regex:

```
slice = "this characters \{}, \[], \(\)"
```

Note that only the opening brace and square bracket need an escape, but both parentheses.

Comment: Note: you'll want to escape the backslashes so that the end string is as above. Your code should look like `"this characters \\{}, \\[], \\(\\)"`

Comment: @Irhala Not true.

Comment: That's how it worked for me and it makes sense according to what I know. Isn't the string parsed first by the python interpreter then as a regex ? Assuming they share some special characters, how would you choose which one "consumes" the escape ?

Comment: @lrhala seems to be right. Just tried to pass single-escaped opening bracket to pd.Series(my_list).str.contains("\[") in pandas 1.0.1 and got DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence `\]`  Same for the other special characters in this answer by @DYZ. Adding second backslash makes the function work allright in all of these cases.